# How can I wrap a div around existing elements?

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I'm trying to parse an existing document and modify it by wrapping a div around some existing form elements.

HTML form looks a bit like this:

```
<form>
  <label for="username">Username:</label>
  <input name="username" type="text" />
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input name="password" type="password" />
</form>
```

I can parse the document OK with Nokogiri and i'm aware of the `wrap` method but i'm struggling to grasp how to select both the label and input tags in one go and then wrap a div around these.  So the result I am looking for is:

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input name="username" type="text" />
  </div>    
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input name="password" type="password" />
  </div>
</form>
```

I have tried various XPaths / CSS selectors and can create a nodeset of just labels/inputs or all of the elements of the whole form.  Is there any way to achieve this modification?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". We can't tell what you've tried. It's better for us to correct your code than for us to write entirely unrelated code and you try to shoehorn it into place. What "various XPaths/CSS selectors" did you write? How did you use them with Nokogiri?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single XPath expression can only return a single collection of nodes, so in order to achieve what you want you will need to make several queries, one for each `label` – `input` pair.

You can select an individual pair with something like this, assuming the markup is well behaved (i.e each `input` has a `label` before it):

```
//label[1] | //label[1]/following-sibling::input[1]
```

This will select the first `label` and the following `input`. However you want to select all such pairs. One way would be to first select all the `label` nodes, and then for each `label` select it and the following input.

```ruby
labels = doc.xpath("//form/label")
labels.each do |l|
  nodes = l.xpath(". | ./following-sibling::input[1]")
  # nodes now contains a label-input pair...
end
```

I don’t think the `wrap` method will work to add a `div` element as an ancestor to each pair, as it will add the element to *each* member of the nodeset. You will probably have to move them manually, something like

```ruby
labels = doc.xpath("//form/label")
labels.each do |l|
  # Select this node and its neighbour.
  nodes = l.xpath(". | ./following-sibling::input[1]")

  # Create the new element, and add it before the label.
  div = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new('div', l.document)
  l.before(div)

  # Move each of the pair onto this new element.
  nodes.each do |n|
    div.add_child(n)
  end
end
```

Note that this method doesn’t move any text nodes, so you may find the whitespace of your document changes a bit.

Comment: Thank you. I had seen a couple of answers to other similar queries but I think your solution is concise and makes sense for this particular situation. Cheers.